# Changing ionic sass variables for individual components

Tags: css, ionic-framework, cross-platform, ionic3

I want to change ionic sass variables for individual components i.e. I want to change

```
$label-md-text-color-focused: red;
```

property differently for different components where I'm using floating labels. Right now these properties are in **theme/src/variables.scss** file and getting applied to every floating label being used in app.

What I've already tried is placing same properties in different components' .scss files to override but no effect at all. App is just loading these properties from variables.scss file.

Any solution for this ?

Comment: thats not possible.. you will have to override the css..check https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/7469

Comment: The ionic sass varible is used in whole app. So you can not do it. But if you want to have different style for different component, why not just add style for element in each component? It is the easy way.

Comment: @Duannx I agree we should add individual style with specific component with plain css. But I'm unable to find plain css for above mentioned property. Can you help me with that ? Thanks

Comment: Please add your html